# Kendo-Listview : Can't use a link as per the proper format of Html inside the template of kendo list

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have model named with Foo

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<Foo>()
                      .Name("listView")
                      .TagName("div")
                      .ClientTemplateId("template")
                      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                                    .Model(model => model.Id("Id"))
                                                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "Home"))
                      )
                      )
```

& Script is :

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">

</script>
```

Inside this how to use a HTML tag format some of tag inside this is not as it is as the HTML with the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to write it as Html with passing the data with `#: data.yourmodelfield #` & then you can show the repeatedly data inside the kendo List with designed CSS.

Eg :

```
<div class="cssclass">
    <a href="Javascript:LoadFunction('/Home/Method1/#: data.fooId#')">#: data.fooName#</a>
</div>
```

Comment: you can redirect your link to javascript function with the parameters and then pass to the controller method from that function.